# Academic conference visa for China

Tags: conference, visa, china

Salam. Has anyone ever applied to any conference in China?

I am having difficulty in filing visa application here in NZ. The Chinese embassy has returned my application without processing twice and the demand "A Letter of Invitation (TE) from local foreign affairs in China"...

I do not have the slightest of idea what it means and why would foreign affairs in China invite me? Can anyone help me in this regard?

Comment: Perhaps a letter from the conference organisers will suffice.

Comment: Or the conference organizers should know the right paperwork.

Comment: I have already submitted the letter from the conference which is auto-generated. The conference organizers replied after 1 week that due to technical issues they cannot respond to queries and looking to resolve the problem.

Comment: Try going to the Chinese embassy and asking there...

Comment: Perhaps you should wait for the conference organizers to resolve the problem.

Comment: Perhaps Travel.SE is better for this.